# Broadcast UPnP over WireGuard

Tags: upnp, wireguard

I have few devices: VDS, custom NAS on linux, laptop PC.
All of that successfully connected to one local subnetwork 10.1.1.0/24

Server configuration:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.1.1.1/24
ListenPort = 5182
PrivateKey = ***

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 10.1.1.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 10.1.1.12/32
```

Typical client:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.1.1.2/32
PrivateKey = ***

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 10.1.1.0/24,224.0.0.0/4
Endpoint = host.name:5182
```

A client interface (server is same)

```
wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.1.1.2/24 scope global hub0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Server listen any address and port

```
UNCONN 0      0                         239.255.255.250:1900       0.0.0.0:*     users:((minidlnad,pid=456,fd=5))
```

DLNA server can't be discovered, when I used OpenVPN this worked perfectly.

So, I tried send a broadcast with `socat` and not receive it on other side, except my real local network.

Comment: after time I has return to this problem and found [the bug](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/11498)

Answer (score 1):

You use the point-to-point device, that doesn't support the broadcast and multicast. Also check the routing table `local` with command `ip route get <broadcast-ip>`. Likely, you will see only single route, that points to the local network, not the wireguard interface.